# NLog: how to prevent full exception details from being logged with ${message} layout renderer?

Tags: nlog

I just want to do some simple logging to the console, and to keep the exception information very brief. I also want to display the supplementary message if it was supplied.

Here is my target:

```
<target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${message} | ${exception:format=message}" />
```

In my code, if I do this:

```
try
{
    throw new DivideByZeroException("Should not divide by zero");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _logger.Error(e, "A supplementary message");
}
```

The following is sent to the console:

`A supplementary message | Should not divide by zero`

This is exactly what I want.

**However**, if instead I omit the supplementary message like 
`_logger.Error(e);` then what happens is I get the full exception dump (stack trace, etc) for the `${message}` layout renderer.

How can I configure NLog so that if no supplementary message is specified, nothing is output for the message? I would be happy if the following was output to the console:

`| Should not divide by zero`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, and because of backwardscompatibility this will be fixed in the next major version (NLog 5)

See [Github issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1034)